# Unable to change the size of VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, size

I accidentally change the whole size of my VScode by pressing Ctrl & -. I tried to zoom in by pressing Ctrl & + and Ctrl & 0 but it does not seem to work. Can someone please help me ? Thank you.

Comment: Deleting the default setting file located at:  %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl + Shift + P` to find shortcut.

- **Editor Zoom Font In/Out** affects only the font size of the editor.
- **View: Zoom In/Out** affects whole UI.

Comment: Under the section related with the display shortcuts, there is only Zoom in/Out, used by Ctrl & = / -. When ı use Ctrl & = nothing happens.